# Most appropriate lapack function to calculate the largest eigenvalue of a small (4x4) non-symmetric, non-sparse real matrix

Tags: c, lapack, eigenvalue

I'm new to lapack and I'm bit overwhelmed by the large number of available functions and their cryptic names.

As per title, I'm looking for the most appropriate lapack function to calculate the largest eigenvalue of a small (4x4) non-symmetric, non-sparse real matrix. I don't need other eigenvalues, just the largest one, and I don't need any eigenvectors.

Due to technical constrains I have to use lapack.

Edit: I've tested SGEEV and I get the correct result, but I was wondering if there is a better choice because I only need the largest eigenvalue and nothing more.

Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? We will not write it for you. With no effort shown this question will be closed and deleted in a very short time

Comment: Hi @0___________, thank you for your kind reply. As I said I'm new to lapack and I'm not asking to write any code for me, just a recommendation for the most appropriate function to use for my needs. Anyway, I've tested SGEEV and I get the correct result, but I was wondering if there is a better choice because I need only the largest eigenvalue and nothing more. Thank you